# How can I make an undertow ELB with servers on different EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, load, load-balancing, undertow

I want to make an undertow ELB and I know how to write but don't know how to connect it between different instances.

For example, on two instances, I have a servlet (receive get messages) and a undertow server class

Project
  servlet.java
  undertowServer.java

in server part, the program receive message from a certain path ("/project") the rest code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try {
        DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
                .setClassLoader(Controller.class.getClassLoader())
                .setContextPath(PATH)
                .setDeploymentName("handler.war")
                .addServlets(
                        servlet("Servlet", Servlet.class)
                        .addMapping("/")
                );


        DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
        manager.deploy();

        HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();
        PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(PATH))
                .addPrefixPath(PATH, servletHandler);

        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(9001, "localhost")
                .setHandler(path)
                .build();
        server.start();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

one instance listen to 9001, the other listen to 9002.

Besides, I have an ELB on the third instance and the code is

```
LoadBalancingProxyClient loadBalancer = new LoadBalancingProxyClient()
                .addHost(new URI("http://localhost:9001"))
                .addHost(new URI("http://localhost:9002"))
                .setConnectionsPerThread(20);

        Undertow reverseProxy = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(80, "localhost")
                .setIoThreads(4)
                .setHandler(new ProxyHandler(loadBalancer, 30000, ResponseCodeHandler.HANDLE_404))
                .build();
        reverseProxy.start();
```

If I write code like this, it would not work. It gives me not found "URL/project" error. But when I send requests directly to the instance(with the port 9001 or 9002), it works. Is there anything I misunderstand?

By the way, i am not sure whether I should use localhost, or the DNS of the EC2 instance

Comment: what 'undertow ' here means?

Comment: it is a server name

Comment: Quite unclear question as to me. Try to abstract from java if it's possible and narrow the question.